# Unable to do full installation of OpenAI Gym - Unable to create process using '"c:\python37-32\python.exe"

Tags: python, pip, openai-gym

I'm trying to do the full installation of OpenAI Gym, using the command: `pip install -e '.[all]'`.

However, I get the error:
`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python37-32\python.exe"  "C:\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install -e '.[all]''`. Anyone knows what this means or came across this issue before?

I'm using Windows 7 (64-bit). Here's the info regarding the Python installed on my computer:
`Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You seem to have several Python versions installed on your computer. One is a 64bit Python, which appears (first) on your `PATH`. Another one is installed in `C:\Python37-32`. According to the name, this seems to be a 32bit Python. Hard to guess what is actually happening on your computer, but try to have the 32 bit version on `PATH` first. May be get rid of the 64 bit version altogether. Some (compiled) Python modules are not available for 64 bit.

Comment: @Adrian. Yep that's exactly what I was looking at today. I realised I had Anaconda 64-bit Python and then C:\Python37-32, which was install incorrectly. I fixed this now. I installed Python 3.7.2, at path C:\Python\Python37-32. Also fixed the `PATH` to point to this. Now if I type `python` command in Window command prompt (CMD), I get the correct Python version: `Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit
(Intel)] on win32` followed by the interactive indicator `>>>`. So all seems ok. So now when I `cd` into the `Gym` repo I cloned locally and ...

Comment: ... then ran the command provided by Joan in the Answer section below: `pip install gym[all]` (without the need for `python -m` part, as I've fixed Python PATH). It started to install everything correctly and all modules were installed successfully, with the exception of `atari-py`. When it got to `atari-py` installation I got so many errors - basically failed to install Atari module. Do you have a Windows computer? If so, have you managed to install `atari-py`? Apparently it's not well supported on Windows and a complete pain to install :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
python -m pip install -e '.[all]'
```

Comment: Thank you Joan. I tried this but this time I got a different error: '.[all]' should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+

Comment: Perhaps ```python -m pip install gym[all]```?

Comment: Thanks Joan. The command you suggested in the comments worked and started installing. However, I faced further issues with installing Atari, with `failed building wheel for atari-py` error. I'm following this post I found: https://github.com/j8lp/atari-py to try to resolve it, but I'm stuck on the last step: `cd atari-py && make && python setup.py install && pip install "gym[atari]"` . It's not working for me. Should conclude this post and start a new post on the issue?

Comment: Yes, since this one seems to be a different problem.